# Set HTML code to tooltip in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to set some HTML text to tooltip element in Angular. Tooltip is bootstrap element. What ever the text I am passing dynamically have some Html content, that is rendering plain text instead Html Content when I am following below approach.  How can I make tooltip will render HTML.

Parent component

```
<checkbox *ngFor="let item of checkboxGroup.checkboxItems"
      [form]="form"
      [key]="item.key"
      [tooltipText]="item.tooltip"
      [labelText]="checkboxLabel(item)"
      >
</checkbox>
```

Child component

```
<aligned-label class="control__label" [labels]="labelText">
<span *ngIf="tooltipText"  class="mdi mdi-information" tooltip="{{tooltipText}}" container="body"></span>
</aligned-label>
```

aligned-label component

```
<div class="aligned-label">
<div *ngFor="let label of getLabels()" [innerHtml]="label">{{label}}</div>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

tooltipText will be having text/Html script

Comment: What library do you use for the tooltip? ngx-bootstrap?

Comment: provide also in your question which version of Angular you're using. This information is missing.

Comment: yes that is from ngx-bootstrap @smnbbrv;

Comment: did you check https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip#dynamic-html ?

Comment: @PierreMallet that was very helpful. Able to get that using `code` <ng-template #popTemplate><div [innerHtml]="tooltipText"></div></ng-template>
                <span *ngIf="tooltipText" class="mdi mdi-information" [tooltip]="popTemplate" container="body"></span> `code`